# Perl recognizing utf8 as Unicode after 4096 bytes

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, buffer, byte-order-mark

I have an application in Perl/CGI where I receive a utf8 txt file and treat its content.

For some reason (I think that Perl divides the file into 4096 bytes buffers and only the first one has the Byte Order Mark) Perl interprets the content of the file as Unicode after 4096 bytes.

If I spread some en dashes ("–") in the middle of the file (at least one for each block of 4k) the program recognizes it as utf8, probably because Unicode doesn't have en dashes.

I'm receiving the txt from an html page and sending it to an scalar variable like this:

```
while(my $l = <$fh>){
    $text .= $l;
}
```

I tried to force utf8 by concatenating each line of the file with an en dash:

```
while(my $l = <$fh>){
    $text .= "–".$l;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Wide character in print at (eval 12) line 94.
```

Does anyone have a tip?
has
Thank you!

Comment: "Unicode doesn't have en dashes". That is untrue. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

Answer (score 3):

Perl can operate on Unicode codepoints, but all I/O is done with bytes. When you print a string with high code points to a normal file handle, you get the “wide character in print” warning.

You should *decode* all input data, and *encode* all your output. The best way to do this is to use PerlIO layers. You can add layers with `binmode`. E.g:

```
use utf8; # This source file is encoded in UTF-8.
          # Else, the literal "–" would be seen as multiple bytes, not one single character.

binmode STDOUT, ":uft8"; # encode all strings (that get printed to STDOUT)
                         # to the binary UTF-8 representation
print "–\n"; # EN DASH – works.
```

When opening a file, you can add PerlIO layers in the open mode, e.g.

```
open my $fh "<:utf8", $filename or die ...;
```

This transparently translates the binary input to codepoints.

Do not concatenate byte strings that contain binary UTF-8 with properly decoded strings – the result will most likely be invalid data. Of course, such issues don't arise when you decode all input.

The way Perl buffers the input should not affect your program; it is likely you misdiagnosed that. Perl does not do encoding detection via BOMs on input files.

In the context of web programming, encoding your output as UTF-8 is a good choice, but make sure to also set the `charset` property in the response headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The HTML document should reiterate this with `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

Comment: Hi amon, thanks for the response.

What do you mean by "print a string with high code points to a normal file handle"? I've already got the "wide character in print" warning another times and never truly understood this.

Everytime I open a file from disk I use:

    open FH, "<:encoding(UTF-8)";

And it goes ok. But how could I do this, as soon the CGI gives me just the $fh?

Comment: @gvieira That is good, but you also need to encode the data when you print it out. This can be done with the `binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"` (or whatever filehandle and encoding you want). Then that warning should go away. A high code point is any character not in Latin-1 (IIRC).

Comment: @gvieira That response was written before your edit. You need to add the `:utf8` layer (or an equivalent layer) on both the input and the output file handle. In both cases, layers can be added with `binmode`, as shown.

Comment: I'm doing a test: `binmode $fh, ":utf8";
open (AUXT, ">"."auxtext.txt");
binmode AUXT, ":utf8";
while (<$fh>){ print AUXT $_; }
close AUXT;`
And I still get the wide char just cause the file uploaded has a '**ç**'. How could it even happen? Edit: The error.log says that the wide char error is in line `print AUXT $_;`

Comment: @gvieira Are you by chance using the `upload` function from the `CGI` module? In that case, try `$fh = $fh->handle` as soon as you obtain it. Could you please also list all applied PerlIO layers after specifying them with `binmode`? You can do so like `say for PerlIO::get_layers(AUXT);` etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
use Encode qw(encode);

$text = join '', <$fh>;

$text = encode("utf8", $text);
```